# Which SharePoint permission role?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site, settings

so I'll be working on this sharepoint site and someone already made a draft for the website and gave me access to edit the site. However, when I go to site settings, I only have these options. 
[image: Site Settings]

I know that there are more options than just these. I'm trying to figure out what permission role I actually have and what permission role do I need to have for full editing and designing control?

Answer (score 1):

You might only have "Design" permission level to this site.

If you want to get full editing and designing control, you need to assign with "Full Control" permission level.